# FindBugs 3 not working in Eclipse Luna

Tags: eclipse, findbugs, eclipse-luna

I try to use the FindBugs 3.0.0 in my Eclipse Luna.
After installing it it should be available on context menu of my JavaProject and under Window -> Preferences -> Java -> Find Bugs.

But it isn't there.

I tried it with installation from Marktplace, Update Site and downloading the Zip and putting it into my Eclipse installation.

Is there anything else I have to do to make it run?

Greeting
Sören

Answer (score 6):

I had the same problem. My eclipse run on JVM 6 and FindBugs didn't work. I switch eclipse to use JVM 7 and this fixed issue. For more info how to switch JVM version that eclipse uses, see this [eclipse Wiki](http://wiki.eclipse.org/Eclipse.ini#Specifying_the_JVM)

Comment: Thanks, it worked by changing the JVM in eclipse.ini as you said (not working by changing installed JREs preferences). And it has not impact on projects preferences.

Answer (score 2):

My installation of FindBugs 3.0.0 in eclipse luna works fine but I´ve installed the 3.0.0.20140629 version. 
As a colleague of me, has the same problem hence I am not going to update it :)

Try to install the earlier version (not using the eclipse marketplace), this should fix your issue in the meantime.