# Which version of FindBugs works with Eclipse Luna?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, findbugs

I have installed the Findbugs plugin via it's [Eclipse update site](http://findbugs.cs.umd.edu/eclipse/).

But when I right click on a project, I do not see any Findbugs options. Looks like there is an issue with Eclipse update site.

Can anyone point me at the right version/way to install Findbugs in Eclipse Luna?

Comment: I'm using findbugs 3.0.0.20140629 in Luna and have no issues. Seems to be the one on the update site aswell. Check your workspace log for errors.

Comment: Do you use a 32bit or a 64bit JDK+Eclipse?

Comment: @AttilaCsipak   I use 64 bit jdk..Looks like i need to use JDK 1.7..But i use jdk 1.6 , installed findbugs 2.0.3 and it works.

Comment: Yes. I just had the same problem with Eclipse Kepler + JDK 1.6. Also, this question is practically a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24981455/findbugs-3-not-working-in-eclipse-luna.

Answer (score 3):

I'm using the Findbugs version available in Eclipse Luna Marketplace (version 3.0.0.20140706-2cfb468) and it works.

Assuming you could install it from the Marketplace:

- The findbugs option is present in this screen-shot when I select a single project or a working set.

  [image: Findbugs]
- The options is not visible (I personally think it would be better if it was disabled rather than not visible) if you select a closed project in your selection. This does not apply to working set containing closed project.

  [image: No findbugs]
- Your project preference will indicate you if Findbugs was successfully installed or not:

  [image: Findbugs Project Preference]
- Check your workspace log, using the Errors view.
- I think Findbugs work only with Java project. If your project is not recognized as a Java project, that may explain it. You should try to create a new Java project, or better a new workspace.

Answer (score 0):

please try to put findbug plugin zip file into dropins folder of eclipse. that might work.
For Example,
C:\Users\PipariyS\AppData\Local\MyEclipse Blue Edition\MyEclipse Blue Edition 10\dropins

Comment: I need to copy the whole zip file/ extract it and copy some libraries into dropins folder? I see plugin, lib folders in the zip

Comment: I copied findbugs-plugin.jar into dropins/plugin folders too but no luck

Comment: you can put zip file directly into dropins folder(not in plugins folder) and restart eclipse.

Comment: i could not fix this issue using any of the way..direct installation/update sites/marketplace  hummm:(